# How to fetch the CKShare object of an already existing share (to get share URL)

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit, cloudkit-sharing

I am trying to allow users of my app to be able to retrieve the iCloud sharing link to a record that they have ALREADY shared.  I can get the URL when creating the share by using the `let share = CKShare(rootRecord: CKRecord)` followed by Apple's `UISharingController`.  However, every time I use this method, the old link becomes invalid and kicks others out of the share they have already joined.  How can I allow the users (the record owners) to fetch a shareable URL for the records `CKShare` object at any time?

```
//Initially shares the record
let share = CKShare(rootRecord: newRecord)
share[CKShare.SystemFieldKey.title] = "Group" as CKRecordValue?        
let modifyRecordsOperation = CKModifyRecordsOperation( recordsToSave: [newRecord, share], recordIDsToDelete: nil)

//Activates the UISharingController (code not shown)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the record has already been shared, you can get the URL to invite additional participants with the following:

```swift
if let shareReference = record.share {
    database.fetch(withRecordID: shareReference.recordID) { (share, error) in
        let shareURL = (share as? CKShare)?.url
    }
}
```

If you wanted to show the `UICloudSharingController` again for an existing share (without it generating a new URL), you could do:

```swift
let sharingController = UICloudSharingController { (_, prepareCompletionHandler) in

    func createNewShare() {
        let operationQueue = OperationQueue()
        operationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1

        let share = CKShare(rootRecord: record)
        share[CKShare.SystemFieldKey.title] = "Title" as CKRecordValue
        share.publicPermission = .readWrite

        let modifyRecordsOp = CKModifyRecordsOperation(recordsToSave: [share, record], recordIDsToDelete: nil)
        modifyRecordsOp.modifyRecordsCompletionBlock = { records, recordIDs, error in
            prepareCompletionHandler(share, self, error)
        }
        modifyRecordsOp.database = database
        operationQueue.addOperation(modifyRecordsOp)
    }

    if let shareReference = record.share {
        database.fetch(withRecordID: shareReference.recordID) { (share, error) in
            guard let share = share as? CKShare else {
                createNewShare()
                return
            }
            prepareCompletionHandler(share, self, nil)
        }
    } else {
        createNewShare()
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you've got multiple issues going on here. I'd recommend going through the UICloudSharingController [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicloudsharingcontroller) carefully.

The first issue is in the code you've provided you're creating a new share each time, when what you want to do is to create it once and then show that share any time you want to interact with it (including getting the share URL). After you create your share you'll probably want to persist that on device somehow (it can be as simple as storing it in UserDefaults).

The second issue is it sounds like you're not instantiating the UICloudSharingController correctly. When you initially create the CKShare you must use the UICloudSharingController [init(preparationHandler:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicloudsharingcontroller/1649607-init) initializer and create the share INSIDE of that.

As per the documentation for the different initializers (emphasis mine):

> **Important**
>
> *You must initialize the controller with the correct initializer*
>   *method*. Do not use init(preparationHandler:) if the CKRecord is
>   already shared. Likewise, do not use init(share:container:) if the
>   CKRecord is not shared. Using the wrong initializer leads to errors
>   when saving the record.

And when you then want to show the shareSheet, you use the UICloudSharingController [init(share:container:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicloudsharingcontroller/1649597-init) initializer, and feed it the share you have persisted to device.

Here's the code provided in the UICloudSharingController documentation for creating the CKShare:

```
func presentCloudSharingController(_ sender: Any) {  guard
    let barButtonItem = sender as? UIBarButtonItem,
    let rootRecord = self.recordToShare else {
    return
  }

  let cloudSharingController = UICloudSharingController { [weak self] (controller, completion: @escaping (CKShare?, CKContainer?, Error?) -> Void) in
    guard let `self` = self else {
      return
    }
    self.share(rootRecord: rootRecord, completion: completion)
  }

  if let popover = cloudSharingController.popoverPresentationController {
    popover.barButtonItem = barButtonItem
  }
  self.present(cloudSharingController, animated: true) {}
}

func share(rootRecord: CKRecord, completion: @escaping (CKShare?, CKContainer?, Error?) -> Void) {
  let shareRecord = CKShare(rootRecord: rootRecord)
  let recordsToSave = [rootRecord, shareRecord];
  let container = CKContainer.default()
  let privateDatabase = container.privateCloudDatabase
  let operation = CKModifyRecordsOperation(recordsToSave: recordsToSave, recordIDsToDelete: []) 
  operation.perRecordCompletionBlock = { (record, error) in
    if let error = error {
      print("CloudKit error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
  }

  operation.modifyRecordsCompletionBlock = { (savedRecords, deletedRecordIDs, error) in
    if let error = error {
      completion(nil, nil, error)
    } else {
      completion(shareRecord, container, nil)
    }
  }

  privateDatabase.add(operation)
}
```

And next time you want to show it, it's much more strait forward:

```
 let share = // yourCKShare
 let container = // yourCKContainer
 let viewController = // yourViewController
 let shareController = UICloudSharingController(share: share, container: container)
 viewController.present(shareController, animated: true)
```

And finally to answer the URL part of your question, the UICloudSharingController is used for all things sharing - while the controller is presenting the share, there's a "Copy Link" button available to the owner (and possibly the user as well if you allow public access - I haven't looked at that as my stuff is private):

[image]

Comment: Awesome thank you so much!  I am still relatively new to swift and coding vocabulary in general (swift is my first language and I am still in high school and haven’t had any professional instruction yet).  My question that I still can’t figure out is how exactly to FETCH an existing CKShare object from the iCloud server so I can place it into the UISharingController.  I know how to fetch normal CK records with both the convenience api and the CKoperations but they do not have the CKShare object attached.  How can I fetch a CKShare object?

Comment: Unfortunately that's probably a bit more than will fit in a comment - I'd recommend doing more research and/or starting a different question. The WWDC videos about CloudKit are good for some basic high-level concept stuff (the WWDC 2016  ones stand out in my mind). I found the concepts behind CloudKit hard to pick up too!

Comment: Hmm actually I guess that was right in the question title so maybe don't start a new question.  Have you tried using either the CKQueryOperation or CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation to get the share?

Comment: If a CKRecord is already shared, shouldn't it be possible to simply downcast, like so: let share = rootRecord as? CKShare

Comment: The rootRecord isn't the CKShare record - they're two different records.